# MySQL user variables in subquery affected by outer query order/group?

Tags: mysql, variables, subquery

I'm trying to write a query that will find the most consecutive of something in my database.  This has led to me trying out variables, which I've never really used before.

The problem I have is my query is giving me exactly the result I think it should, but when I use it as a subquery inside another query, it all seems to go to pot when I add the group by/order by clauses.

**Is this normal, and if so what tends to be the solution?  Or have I made a simple mistake?**

The results of my subquery are perfect, and all I'm trying to do in the outer query is select the maximum of the "consecutive" column that I've created.  This column takes the form of

```
@r := IF(nFound=nThis,@r + 1,0)
```

I.e. it simply counts up 1 for each row that fits my where/order arrangement, and resets to 0 if a match isn't found.

I was hoping that the subquery results would be "set" and simply used as the values before being used in the main query.

I liken this to excel;  sometimes you want to "paste as values" rather than copying all of the formulas across, if you get what I mean.  Is there a simple way to do so in MySQL?

I wondered if creating a view might "solidify" the data set, but then found out variables aren't allowed in views!

**EDIT**
OK, here's the query.  It's not pretty, but I've been hacking around and trying lots of things.  If you remove the last 2 lines and the "MAX" function it works fine, with them it only returns a single row, rather than 10 rows.

I've never used a cross join before today either; virtually everything I do normally seems to be just "JOIN" or "LEFT JOIN"s, but today it seemed necessary.

Basically the idea is to retrieve the maximum number of chronologically consecutive events that each person has been present at.  Feel free to amend as you see fit!

The "P.person < 10" was just a test.  There are in fact thousands of people, but if I tried to do it on everyone at once it was sitting and doing nothing for ages - the crossjoin getting too big, I assume?

```
SET @r=0;

SELECT person,MAX(nConsec)  FROM (

    SELECT @r := IF(nFound=person,@r + 1,0) AS nConsec
       test.* 

    FROM (SELECT P.person, event, tDate, MAX(C.person) AS nFound
        FROM PEOPLE P
            CROSS JOIN EVENTS E
            LEFT JOIN COMPETITORS C ON C.event=E.event AND C.person = P.person

        WHERE P.person < 10
            AND tDate < NOW()

        GROUP BY P.person, event, tDate
            ORDER BY P.person ASC, tDate ASC
    ) test

) test2

GROUP BY person
    ORDER BY MAX(nConsec) DESC
```

**EDIT 2**
OK I've no idea what, but while changing some things to preserve a bit of anonymity, I seem to have inadvertently fixed my own code... A pleasant surprise, but annoying that no amount of ctrl-Z and ctrl-shift-Zing seems to be showing me what I was doing wrong in the first place!

Any opinion/advice on the mess I've got still appreciated.  I'm sure I can do something cleverer that doesn't use a cross join.  There's abotu 30,000 rows in "people" and 1000 in "events", and about 500 competitors per event, so I can see why a cross join gives me issues (15 billion rows I make that...).  Query takes 0.6 seconds for those 10 IDs that I picked out, 34 seconds if I raise it to 1000 IDs.

Comment: Hmm, seem to have fixed it.... have a related query in the 2nd edit though if you're feelign helpful!

Answer (score 0):

What does this do for you:

```
SELECT person, MAX(nConsec) AS numConsecutive FROM (
    SELECT person, COUNT(*) AS nConsec FROM (
        SELECT @r := @r + (COALESCE(@person, P.person) <> P.person) as consecutive, @person := P.person AS person FROM (
            SELECT @r := 0, @person := NULL
        ) vars
        JOIN PEOPLE P
        JOIN EVENTS E
        LEFT JOIN COMPETITORS C
            ON C.person = P.person
            AND C.event = E.event
        ORDER BY tDate
    )
    GROUP BY consecutive
)
```

Modified from code found at http://www.dancewithgrenades.com/blog/mysql-consecutive-row-streaks.

Note that if you're counting across multiple people, you need to keep track of the person you're counting for (`@person` variable). I think this should run quicker though, mostly due to the lack of `GROUP`ing in the innermost subquery which was probably having a large impact on performance. If performance still isn't good enough, then I'd suggest creating a column in `PEOPLE` to hold this consecutive attendance value, modify the query to work on only one person at a time, and run the query for different sets of users at different times to update the value in `PEOPLE`.

Oh and as far as `CROSS JOIN`s — in MySQL, `CROSS JOIN` is equivalent to `INNER JOIN` is equivalent to `JOIN`. You've used cross joins before, you just didn't realize it. ;)

Comment: OK, but I've never joined without an "on" clause.  I did suspect when I typed it (tbh I only typed it as I saw it somewhere else) that it was the same as the ON-less JOIN I had been doing a few moments earlier.  But as I say, I've never used those before either.

Comment: @Codemonkey Without an `ON` clause, an inner join will match every row in the left table with every row in the right - in this case, match every person with every event. Then you left join the competitions to figure out which person-event rows have a match.